# Integration over time by having derivation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Assume we want to find the following integration:

\begin{equation}\int_{t=0}^{\infty} p(t)dt\end{equation}

where $p(0)=p$ and also $$\frac{dp(t)}{dt}=-p(t)(1-p(t))\mu$$.

Is there any easy way to exploit the second equation and calculate the first integration?

Any comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: See [the logistic model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).

Comment: You have the ODE $\dot p=\mu p(p-1)$, thus $p=\frac{\dot p}{\mu(p-1)}$.